# Perl CGI::Validate install / usage fails

Tags: perl, installation, cgi, cpan

I have installed the Perl [CGI::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/~zenin/CGI-Validate-2.000/Validate.pm) module via cpan. I had to force the install due to an error in installation - I get the same error when I try to use the module at all (unsurprisingly).

> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /usr/local/share/perl5/CGI/Validate.pm" line 216., referer: ...

Is this a bug with the Validate module? For reference - line 216 (and the following few lines) of Validate.pm:

```
unless (scalar @{ $form{$field} } or $fields{$field}{optional}) {
    $Blank{$field} = qq(Required field "$field" contains no data);
    next;
}
```

Anything obvious?

Comment: `$form{$field}` is undefined, so it cannot use that inside of the `@{ }` dereference. Also that thins was last updated in 1998. Which test is breaking? I'll try to install it on my machine. What system are you using? Version of Perl, OS, system architecture.

Comment: On a second thought, if you look at the [CPAN Testers results](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=CGI-Validate+2.000) it's pretty clear it is not going to work on more recent Perls (where recent is newer than 9 years). You should let this one go. Or you could try to fix it and submit a patch, but since CGI is not in core any more, and its use is discouraged, I would not waste time with that.

Comment: Thanks for that. What is generally suggested to be used instead of CGI?

Comment: And furthermore, what is the suggested method of form validation when using Perl (I can't seem to find any recent documentation or blogs). If you could provide me with some reading material, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you just have a form, CGI would be fine. There is https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI-FormBuilder/lib/CGI/FormBuilder.pod for example. If you want to build a larger application, look at modern frameworks like Dancer2, Mojolicious or Catalyst. Also see https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho#Task::Kensho::WebDev:-Web-Development, but remember that for CGI environments Moose-based stuff is a bit slow if it's loaded per invocation.

Comment: @simbabque - I think I have a patch for this, but I'm not familiar with who/where I'd submit it.  Do you have some idea where the project is maintained?

Comment: @Carl this thing has not seen updates almost 20 years. You can first try to email the author. There is an address in the documentation at https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Validate. There is an RT at https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CGI-Validate that has an open ticket from 9 years ago with no input. If the author doesn't respond, you can ask the PAUSE admins to take over the module or become a co-maintainer. The process on how to do that is documented in https://www.cpan.org/modules/04pause.html#takeover. Or you can fork and release under a different name. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score -2):

the build work only in this enviroments :
   Windows (32bit) Perl 5.10
   Linux (32bit) Perl 5.10

on other Enviroments the build fail , eg win64bit linux64bit MacOsx with Perl Ver 5.8 , 5.12 . 5.14, 5.16 , 5.18 , 5.20 , 5.22
this may be due to the droped support to the CGI package

look at this page for more detail
http://code.activestate.com/ppm/CGI-Validate/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although this may provide an answer to the question, the link may become unavailable in the future, so it's always better to add a summary of the content. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you all just new to provide help at Stack Overflow , but i will always use you tip